# How to allow a domain and block all subdomains in dnsmasq?

Tags: dnsmasq

In my `dnsmasq.conf` file, I have either one of two sets of rules:

Set 1:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8

server=/firebaseio.com/#
address=/*.firebaseio.com/
```

Set 2:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8

server=/firebaseio.com/8.8.8.8
address=/*.firebaseio.com/
```

Running `dig firebaseio.com` using set 1 gives `127.0.0.1`, but using set 2 give a valid IP address. Why does not the first set give a valid IP? Is not the rule `server=/firebaseio.com/#` supposed to fetch the IP address from the "the standard servers" defined by `server=8.8.8.8`?

Answer (score 0):

You used `address` before.

Quote from [`man dnsmasq`](https://dnsmasq.org/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

> **A, --address=/<domain>[/<domain>...]/[<ipaddr>]**
> Specify an IP address to return for any host in the given domains. A (or AAAA) queries in the domains are never forwarded and always replied to with the specified IP address which may be IPv4 or IPv6.

So you configured dnsmasq to always return a specific address for these domains, but omitted the address. Hence dnsmasq did not return an address.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't clear enough. My question is: Why does NOT the rule `server=/firebaseio.com/#` forward the domain to 8.8.8.8? Is not it supposed to do that? In the setup above, doing `dig firebaseio.com` gives no domain, meaning that the first rule is skipped, and the domain gets blocked by the second rule. This doesn't happen if I specify `server=/firebaseio.com/8.8.8.8` explicitly (firebaseio.com works but not its subdomains).

Comment: Most probably the order of the directions matters. Try switching them.

Comment: I have completely rephrased the question and simplified it..